# Custom Selector For NSSortDescriptor and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am running into a bit of trouble and I was wondering if someone could provide some guidance.

I am attempting to create section headers with the following order: ["Push", "Busy", "Finished", "Canceled"].

Unfortunately, this order cannot be realized with a simple "ascending YES/NO" ... I have to add a custom compare selector ... something like this ..:

**Where "states" maps to ["Push", "Busy", "Finished", "Canceled"]

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortStates = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"states"
                                                           ascending:NO 
                                                            selector:@selector(compareCustom:)];
```

Therefore, I implemented a "compareCustom" ... however, it turns out that I cannot implement a custom sorter as the following exception results:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: compareCustom:'

For reference, the sortDate is implemented by :

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[sortStates]
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:context
                                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:@"states"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

So it looks like I cannot implement a compareCustom which returns a NSComparisonResult? I feel like it should be possible.. but I am unable to figure out how. If someone can provide some advice I would really appreciate it!

Also for reference, here is my "compareCustom" method

```
-(NSComparisonResult)compareCustom:(NSString *)anotherState {
if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Push"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Canceled"]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Push"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Busy"]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Push"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Finished"]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Push"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Finished"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Canceled"]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Finished"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Busy"]) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
}
else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Finished"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Finished"]) {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Finished"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Busy"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Finished"]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}
else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Busy"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Canceled"]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Busy"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Busy"]) {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}

else if ([(NSString *)self isEqualToString:@"Busy"] && [anotherState isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
}

else {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW1) custom sort doesn't work with SQLite persistent store:

> The SQL store, on the other hand, compiles the predicate and sort
>   descriptors to SQL and evaluates the result in the database itself.
>   This is done primarily for performance, but it means that evaluation
>   happens in a non-Cocoa environment, and so sort descriptors (or
>   predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work. The supported sort
>   selectors are compare: and caseInsensitiveCompare:, localizedCompare:,
>   localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:, and localizedStandardCompare: (the
>   latter is Finder-like sorting, and what most people should use most of
>   the time). In addition you cannot sort on transient properties using
>   the SQLite store.

So it seems you can't simply force `NSFetchedResultsController` to display sections in other than alphabetical order.

But you can use a workaround. Add additional, persistent attribute of integer type to your entity (let's call it `sectionOrder`). Set its value according to the `states` property (so it will be 0 for `"Push"`, 1 for `"Busy"` etc.) You can do that in `awakeFromInsert` method, for example.

Then use `@"sectionOrder"` as both `sectionNameKeyPath` and the keypath in sort descriptor. You can set section titles to be "Push", "Busy" etc. using this `UITableViewDataSource` method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.controller sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo.objects.firstObject name];
}
```

Credits to this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793239/2128900).

Answer (score 5):

The `NSSortDescriptor` constructor that you're using attempts to call the specified selector on the objects held at the property named `@"states"`. I'm not sure what this value is, but it looks like they might be `NSSortDescriptor` objects based on the error you're seeing.

Instead of trying to find a selector on an object which may or may not exist, use the block constructor:

You should also really consider rewriting your comparison with integers or something to make it smaller:

```
static NSArray *stateOrder = @[@"Push", @"Busy", @"Finished", @"Cancelled"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortStates = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"states"
                                                    ascending:NO
                                                   comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
  NSInteger state1 = [stateOrder indexOfObject:obj1];
  NSInteger state2 = [stateOrder indexOfObject:obj2];
  if (state1 < state2) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
  } else if (state1 > state2) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
  }
  return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: This won't work with `NSFetchRequest` when using SQLite store.

Comment: Perhaps, but he could also just not filter the results in the initial query and then use this `NSSortDescriptor` to do it after the query responds.

Comment: That's true, but as OP uses `NSFetchedResultsController` it might be better to do the sort directly in the fetch request

Comment: Thanks Ian. I might actually end up going with filtering after the query. It might be cleaner. Thank you!