# Force specific NSFetchedResultsController section to bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to move one specific section returned by my NSFetchedResultsController is put on the bottom. I want to keep the sort order of the other sections. Is there a way to override the specific order?

Here is my NSFetchedResultsController creation:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:teacherString, descriptor, nil]];
    NSString *downloadedString = @"Downloaded";
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"
status like[cd] %@",downloadedString];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"title"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

For example I want to get the title that starts with U to always show on the bottom of the UITableView, but still respond to new objects inserts appropriately.

When I use the sort descriptors, it sorts the sections and then the rows in the sections.

Comment: Have you checked the other initialisers of `NSSortDescriptor` ?

Comment: I have, but I guess I don't understand how adding comparitors will help solve this.

Comment: One way would be to change the tableView (and FRC) delegate methods to rearrange the order of the sections: the trick is to build a different indexPath for the table (using `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]`).  You need to think through carefully the mapping from the FRC indexPath to the TV indexPath, and vice versa, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: You can use `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection` as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27972020/2128900